# Hibernate delete with joins without using IN

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I have the following query that works but it is too slow because it is using IN:

```
_session.CreateQuery(@"
    delete OrderItem oi
    where oi in
         (select i
          from OrderItem i
          where i.Product.Id = :productId
          and i.Order.Company.Id = :companyId
          and i.Order.Campaign.Id :campaignId
          and i.Order.OrderStatus = :orderStatus)
    ")
    .SetParameter("productId", productId)
    .SetParameter("companyId", companyId)
    .SetParameter("campaignId", campaignId)
    .SetParameter("orderStatus", orderStatus)
    .ExecuteUpdate();
```

Is there a way to use native query where you can simply use joins for deletion like:

```
DELETE posts
FROM posts
INNER JOIN projects ON projects.project_id = posts.project_id
WHERE projects.client_id = :client_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use [`Session.createSQLQuery()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-querying-nativesql) and you can use plain SQL.